# AuthGuard: OnAuthStateChanged VS check token in Angular 5 + Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, angular5

Everytime an user **signup**, the following code is excetue:

```
this.router.navigate(['/']);
firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken()
   .then(
      (token: string) => this.token = token
    )
```

getToken method is so defined:

```
getToken() {
   firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken()
     .then(
       (token: string) => this.token = token
      );
   return this.token;
}
```

I save the Token because I have a Guard for the routing that checks if the user has the token:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
   return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
}
```

Now, I just read in the documentation of Firebase that is a good practice to use **onAuthStateChanged()** to check if the user is signed in:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
   } else {
      // No user is signed in.
   }
});
```

So, what is the best way to define if a (valid) user is signed in application with Angular + Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function to check if a user is logged in (using angularfire2, which is a lot of help because it provides you with wrappers in an Angular Way to the firebase js sdk https://github.com/angular/angularfire2):

```
isLoggedIn(){

var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(res => {
    if (res && res.uid) {
      console.log('user is logged in');
      resolve(true);
    } else {
      console.log('user not logged in');
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
});

return promise;

}
```

This is how you would use the function:

```
this.auth.isLoggedIn().then(
    (val) => {
      if(val){

        //Do your re-direct

      }else{
        //send alert or something
      }
    }
);
```